# How to register dynamic BroadcastReceiver with permissions?

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to setup a dynamic broadcast receiver inside my service to receive broadcasts from another application. The twist is I want to require broadcaster to have specific permissions.

In AndroidManifest file of service application I created permission using normal protection leve. Application that will be broadcasting is using above mentioned permission. Broadcast is sent as following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Utils.ACTION_SEND_BUS_MESSAGE);
intent.putExtra(BusMessage.class.getSimpleName(), msg);
sendBroadcast(intent, Utils.PERMISSION_SEND_MESSAGE);
```

And in service receiver is register as:

```
registerReceiver(receiver, receiver.getIntentFilter(), Utils.PERMISSION_SEND_MESSAGE, null);
```

Unfortunately broadcasts to do not arrive to receiver. Removing permission from sendBroadcast and registerReceiver does allow broadcasts to be received.

I have also tested broadcaster to make sure that required permission is granted, which it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The twist is I want to require broadcaster to have specific permissions.

However, you wrote more than that in your code.

> Broadcast is sent as following:

In your code, you use `sendBroadcast(intent, Utils.PERMISSION_SEND_MESSAGE)`. Quoting [the documentation for that flavor of `sendBroadcast()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String%29) (with emphasis added):

> String naming a permission that **a receiver must hold in order to receive your broadcast**.

Your `sendBroadcast()` requires the receiver to hold whatever `Utils.PERMISSION_SEND_MESSAGE` is, and apparently it does not.

Comment: Doesn't registerReceiver set permission for the receiver using third argument? registerReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler)

Comment: @jM2.me: That is where you say that the sender has to hold a permission. Simply get rid of the second parameter to `sendBroadcast()` to solve your problem.

Comment: I am probably making things more complicated, but goal was for receiver to accept broadcasts from applications holding Utils.PERMISSION_SEND_MESSAGE, and for broadcaster to send broadcasts to receivers that are holding Utils.PERMISSION_SEND_MESSAGE as well. Your comment made me realize that custom permission were declared but only used in broadcaster application. All I had to do is use same permission in receiver application.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of methods. Check ContextWrapper class. Adding some samples.

```
 @Override
public Intent registerReceiver(
    BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, int flags) {
    return mBase.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, flags);
}

@Override
public Intent registerReceiver(
    BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter,
    String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler) {
    return mBase.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, broadcastPermission,
            scheduler);
}

@Override
public Intent registerReceiver(
    BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter,
    String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler, int flags) {
    return mBase.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, broadcastPermission,
            scheduler, flags);
}

/** @hide */
@Override
@UnsupportedAppUsage
public Intent registerReceiverAsUser(
    BroadcastReceiver receiver, UserHandle user, IntentFilter filter,
    String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler) {
    return mBase.registerReceiverAsUser(receiver, user, filter, broadcastPermission,
            scheduler);
}
```